# plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to android.I am using android studio 1.1.0.When i am building my project it says
"Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found".What should i do?

Here is my "build.gradle" file-:\
                                                                                    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to   all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
       jcenter()
     }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }}

  allprojects {
   repositories {
    jcenter()
    }}
```

and here is "build.gradle" file of module 'app'-:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
     compileSdkVersion 22
     buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "healthcare.prescro.com.prescro"
     minSdkVersion 17
     targetSdkVersion 22
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
   }
 buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
  }}

  dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
      compile project(path: ':backend_gcm', configuration: 'android-endpoints')}
```

Here is the log-:

> 2015-10-02 00:07:36,306 [  73561]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask -        Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. 
>       com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.LocationAwareExternalSystemException: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.createUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectImportErrorHandler.java:103)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(BaseProjectImportErrorHandler.java:153)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(BaseGradleProjectResolverExtension.java:358)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:151)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:322)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:367)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:333)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:203)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:116)
>       at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:64)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:406)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:483)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:471)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:380)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:419)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:149)

Answer (score 5):

Replace:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0.'
```

with:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
```

Your primary problem is coming from the trailing `.`, which causes your version to not match anything.